# Trying to make connection to a node js socket by passing json data but gettting connection error

Tags: c#, json, sockets, uwp

Trying to make connection to a node js socket by passing json data but gettting connection error  below is the code .its a connection error but why it occuring did not caught.i tried to connect to same server through another fresh uwp it is working properly .nut when i am trying to implement it in my existing uwp it's not connecting

```
   using CustomSplash.Managers.SpecialistManager;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
    using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
    using Windows.UI.Core;
    using Windows.UI.Popups;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

    namespace CustomSplash.Extras
    {
        public class Utility
        {
            public string method { get; set; }
            public string mail_id { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }

            public static bool isEmptyString(string str)
            {
                if (str.Equals(string.Empty) || str.Equals(""))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            public static string getFormatedDate(DateTime dateAndTime)
            {
                string date = dateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Log.print(date);
                return date;

            }

            public async static void showMessageDialog(string message, string title)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }

            public async static Task<string> getSysFileJsonSendToServer(string studentName, string studentEmail, string studentPhoneNumber, string studentPassw)
            {

                DateTime dateTimeCurrent = await WebServiceManager.GetDateFromServer();
                DateTime localTime = dateTimeCurrent.ToLocalTime();
                string localDateTimeString = Utility.getFormatedDate(localTime);
                string finalJsonObjectToServer = string.Empty;

                Stream serverStream = null;
                string readData = string.Empty;
                string msg = "Conected to Chat Server ...";

                var student = new Utility
                {
                    method = "login",
                    mail_id = "abc@gmail.com",
                    password = "123456",
                };
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student);//now in json format
                                                                   // Declare member objects
                                                                   // Client for tcp, network stream to read bytes in socket
                Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket tcpClient = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();

                // Purpose:     Connect to node.js application (lamechat.js)
                // End Result:  node.js app now has a socket open that can send
                //              messages back to this tcp client application

                Windows.Networking.HostName serverHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName("10.2.11.25");
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(serverHost, "5000");

                // Purpose:     Send the text in typed by the user (stored in
                //              txtOutMsg)
                // End Result:  Sends text message to node.js (lamechat.js)
                serverStream = tcpClient.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(serverStream);
                string request = json;
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(request);
                await writer.FlushAsync();
                return finalJsonObjectToServer;
            }
            public async static Task showMessageDialogAndClose(string message, string title)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);
                dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Close", Id = 0 });
                var res = await dialog.ShowAsync();

                if ((int)res.Id == 0)
                {
                    CoreApplication.Exit();
                }
            }
            public async static Task showMessageDialogAndBack(string message, string title)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);
                dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Close", Id = 0 });
                var res = await dialog.ShowAsync();

                if ((int)res.Id == 0)
                {
                    Frame currentFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                    if (currentFrame.CanGoBack)
                    {
                        currentFrame.GoBack();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably the code real wan't getting compiled.  I always check the project bin folder when issue like this occur and verify the timestamp of the executable to see if the code real did get compiled.

Comment: Can you build this project successfully? Which code line throw exception? Did you have details about exception?

Comment: Exceptions occurs at    line                                                                                   await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(serverHost, "5000");                                       serverStream = tcpClient.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();